# read multiple json objects in a single string android

Tags: android, json, sockets

I'm using socket programming in my application and i send commands with Json format and the problem is socket buffers the messages and sends them all at once so when i get string on the other side i get non-Json object like this

```
{"action":"ping","time":1684610209993}{"action":"ping","time":1684610210225}{"action":"ping","time":1684610210447}{"action":"ping","time":1684610210670}{"action":"ping","time":1684610210888}{"action":"ping","time":1684610211107}{"action":"ping","time":1684610211328}{"action":"ping","time":1684610211545}{"action":"ping","time":1684610211762}{"action":"ping","time":1684610211983}{"action":"ping","time":1684610212203}{"action":"ping","time":1684610212419}{"action":"ping","time":1684610212636}{"action":"ping","time":1684610212854}{"action":"ping","time":1684610213074}{"action":"ping","time":1684610213295}{"action":"ping","time":1684610213532}{"action":"ping","time":1684610213751}
```

and when i try to parse it i get JsonParserException. i want to process each object separately

Comment: If you are certain that they will always come exactly like this, divide the strings into substrings at the `}{` points to get individual JSON objects.

Comment: there are some actions that are nested json objects and in get error in the parsing @CommonsWare

Comment: Then perhaps your sender could better delimit the individual JSON objects, rather than sending them in such a way that they are difficult to separate.

Comment: Some JSON libraries know how to stop reading at the final `}` and then you can read the next object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so here's what i did

i check if the string is multiple json commands with this function:

```
private fun isMutipleCommands(obj: String): Boolean {
    return obj.count {
        it == '}'
    } > 1
}
```

then if it is, ill pass the string to command separator:

```
private fun handleMultipleJsonObjectInString(obj: String) {
    try {
        var position = 0
        var startPosition = -1
        var openedNestedObjects = 0
        var tmp_str = obj
        tmp_str.forEach {
            if (it == '{' && startPosition == -1) {
                startPosition = position
            } else if (it == '{' && startPosition != -1) {
                openedNestedObjects++
            } else if (it == '}' && openedNestedObjects > 0) {
                openedNestedObjects--
            } else if (it == '}' && openedNestedObjects == 0) {
                val tmp = JsonParser.parseString(
                    tmp_str.substring(
                        startPosition,
                        position + 1
                    )
                ).asJsonObject
                handleCommand(tmp)
                startPosition = -1
                openedNestedObjects = 0
                Log.e(TAG, "handleMultipleJsonObjectInString: " + tmp.toString())
            }
            position++
        }
    } catch (e: JsonParseException) {
        Log.e(
            TAG,
            "handleMultipleJsonObjectInString: Error parsing : " + e.message + " : " + e.cause
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW it doesn't work if there's a { or } inside a string. By the time you handle that, you are halfway to writing your own JSON parser.